# REACTJS: obj.push() and obj.concat is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an error that my `obj.push()` and `obj.concat()` is not a function but I am not so sure why. Here is my code:

```
onSearch = () => {
    var obj = {
        product: [
            {
                field: "is_published",
                filter_value: 1
            },

            {
                field: "order_mode",
                filter_array: [
                    "fcfs",
                    "purchase-order"
                ]
            },

            {
                relationship: "store",
                filter_object: {
                    field: "slug",
                    filter_value: "sample"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    if (this.state.search !== "") {
        obj.push(
        {
            field: "name",
            text_search: this.state.search
        }
        )
    }
    var obj2 = {
        taxonomies: [
            [
                {   field: "type",
                    filter_value: "seller"
                },
                {   field: "slug",
                    filter_value: "brand"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
    var conc = obj.concat(obj2);

    var { getProductSearch } = this.props
    getProductSearch(obj.concat(obj2))
}
```

`product` and `taxonomies` are stored in different variables but I need to pass them as one array to `getProductSearch` and for that, I need to use `concat()`. then I need to use `push()` because I want to add an object to the array `obj`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `obj` is an object, not an array. `push` is a method of `Array.prototype`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: You are calling `Arrays` methods on an `Object` hence the errors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat
You should be calling `obj.product.push()` for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is because you can't push onto an object. [Push is used for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

To make this work you could instead change your code to push onto the array in your object by doing.

```
obj.product.push(
    {
        field: "name",
        text_search: this.state.search
    }
)
```

If you are trying to make product dynamic where there are multiple products like [fruits, veggies, meat] then you could change it simply by doing

```
onSearch(productName)
obj[productName].push(
    {
        field: "name",
        text_search: this.state.search
    }
)
```

This would let you call onSearch(veggies) and push only to that array if you set it up that way.

Comment: what about concat?? do I do it like `obj.product.concat(obj2.taxonomies)`?

Comment: that should work as well, if you want to play with and test this out checkout this page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat